# Custom group items recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, customization, recyclerview-layout

My destination is customize recyclerview .Item will join into a group if we tap to button link. and there is one button "link" between two item.
I need some advice from you, guys. Thanks .

like this :

[image]

Comment: You can use item decorator and customise it fit your need.

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly about decorator? The decorator will be above two item, How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove spacing between view holders and add a View to left side into your ViewHolder after you need to change the color of this view. It will look like on your image.

Comment: How about the button between two item ,sir?

Comment: No good ideas because you will need to add another type of view holder

Answer (score 0):

first put your circularview in the bottom and overlapped one part to the item
like this- [image]

then use this code:

```
   public class ItemDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {
        private final int mSpace;

        public ItemDecorator(int space) {
            this.mSpace = space;
        }

        @Override
        public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
            int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view);
            if (position != 0)
                outRect.top = mSpace;
        }
    }
```

After that add your decoration to recyclerView before setting its layout manager, and we are done.

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

 mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ItemDecorator(-50));
```

using this code the item of recyclerview overlapped each other.

Comment: I have set verOverlap to -100. but items don't overlapped each other

Comment: @DươngNguyễnVăn i have little bit changes in mycode, please try this.

Comment: noting changes. my screen still margin so far like the photo above